# Pandas shift with multiIndex causes numpy exception when attempting to print the results

Tags: pandas, set, shift, levels

I've created a 3-level multi-index pandas dataframe where the first level (0) holds the cell (1-20 or 0-19), level (1) holds various attributes and level (2) holds the attributes values.
This works without an issue until I determine I need to 'shift' the data

```
the_matrix["CELL_01"] = the_matrix["CELL_01"].shift(-1)
```

If I attempt to print the matrix using a simple print statement it works

```
print("the_matrix: " + str(the_matrix))
```

I then re-labeled columns to reflect the shift

```
new_level_0_columns = ["CELL_20", "CELL_01", "CELL_02", "CELL_03", ...]
the_matrix.columns.set_levels(new_level_0_columns, level=0, inplace=True, verify_integrity=False)
```

Though the shift actually works and if I look at various places in the_matrix I can see the shifted results and they are what is expected.

```
print("CELL_01.type_of_data" + str(the_matrix.loc[:, ("CELL_01", "type_of_data")]))
```

However, if I attempt to just print the matrix (again) using the same print statement:

```
print("the_matrix:" + str(the_matrix))
```

I get the error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U32'), dtype('<U32')) ->dtype('<U32')
```

Errors appear to be directly related to the "set_levels" command.  Interesting that if I change the parameter on the set_levels command for "verify_integrity=True" I get a different error and as the set_levels command is being executed:

```
ValueError: On level 0, code max (20) >= length of level(20). NOTE: this index is in an inconsistent state
```

But the "new_level_0_columns" are correct.  What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

So to help others in the future, I discovered through the debug console, what the issue is.

A check of the_matrix.columns.levels(0) PRIOR to set_levels command show

```
Index(['CELL_01', 'CELL_02', ... 'CELL_20', 'index')]
```

The new_level_0_columns does NOT include the "index" reference.  It only has the shifted column names.

If you look at these values after the set_levels command is issued, it shows

```
`Index([None,                    '',
       'CELL_20',
       'CELL_01',
       etc...])`
```

If you issue new_level_0_columns.append("index") BEFORE issuing the set_levels
command the problem is solved.